# Работа с Word в php (doc, docx, rtf)

Tags: php, wordpress, ms-word, docx, doc

Возможно ли реализовать на **php** скрипт который будет применять к вордовскому файл макрос написанный на **vba**? Что для этого нужно, в каком направлении *гуглить*?

Answer (score 0):

Это сделать можно, но только если сервер работает под Windows, и там установлен Office.

Скрипт php должен вызывать

```
$app = new COM( 'Word.application' ); // Вы не сможете создать COM-объект под Linux.
```

Потом нечто вроде

```
$app->Application->Run( 'Имя_Макроса' ); // Это пример для Excel.
```

Comment: А возможно функционал макроса на vba перенести на php, а затем применить к файлу word? Без сервера на windows

Comment: Возможно. На Linux вы можете оперировать с помощью php содержимым Word-файла.